# Redirect to either login page or lock page on session time

Tags: php, session, redirect

Thank you in advance for any one who comes in to my rescue

Case:

I have a login page that users for my system use to login, after loginnng in, they are entitled to an idle moment for about 10 minutes, after that they are redirected to the login page again to enter their details.

Needed:

Am trying to implement a redirect to the other page which is the lock page where the user will only enter password without entering his username but this is really giving me headache because when the session is destroyed, the user's credentials are all cleared hence requiring him/her to enter both the username and password. Is there any way i can store the user's username when the session is timed out so that its echoed in a hidden field on the lock screen.

Am trying to implement this with php

Comment: You can save the username to a local variable, destroy session, recreate with just username and a flag like `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;`. You can use a database, you can use a text file, you can use javascript `localStorage/sessionStorage` you can use $_GET by redirecting to that url with the username in the URL...Tons of methods.

Answer (score 2):

Login.php
//On Load

```
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['UserName'])) { ?> <style> username { display:none; } </style> <script> docuemnt.GetElementById("username").value = <?php echo $_SESSION['UserName']; ?> </script <?php
```

//After Login

```
$_SESSION['UserName'] = $username;
$_SESSION['Login'] = 'True';
$_SESSION['Time'] = time();
```

Make in every page this code

```
$time = $_SESSION['Time'];
$time_check=$time-600;
if($time<$time_check) {
  $_SESSION['login'] = 'False';
  header(location:login.php);
```

Comment: I will have to try this. I will be needing to do something similar with a lock screen for my application. I'll report back if I can remember to look at this, and post :)

Answer (score 0):

You can Do it by adding username in url and extract that on that page using $_GET variable.Before destroying session store the username from session variable to another and put that in url.

Answer (score 0):

let me correct you here dude,

working version:

```
  $time = $_SESSION["time"];
  $time_check = $time + 5;
  if(time() > $time_check)
  {
    $_SESSION["logged"] = "False";
    header("Refresh: 1; url=lockscreen.php");
  }
```

and you forgot the "" in header

Answer (score -1):

Don't destroy the session, just unset the userdata you need but not the username.

Comment: Session is timed out so that info is lost